# Configurating HTTPS/SSL in OC4J (mod_oc4j not found)

Tags: jakarta-ee, oc4j

I'm trying to configure my OC4J Standalone (version 10.1.3) to use HTTPS/SSL. The problem is that in every tutorial I must configure the mod_oc4j.conf, but in my directory there is no such file.

I don't know what to do.
 -Do I have to create it? (where? is there a sample of it?)
 -Do I have to download it from somewhere?
 -Do I have to generate it?

Any help is welcome.
If there are any good tutorials, please post it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may be of some help:
http://technology.amis.nl/2004/11/21/quick-and-easy-ssl-in-oc4j-standalone/

I would recommend checking in the server.xml file what file do you use for your defualt web-site and then copy and rename it to `secure-web-site.xml` (as in the link)